# Null pointer exception for creating array of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have checked almost all kinds of declarations for an array of objects. Please suggest the required changes.This code gives me a null pointer exception as follows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at objarray.main(objarray.java:33)

```
import java.util.*;
class Prod {
    private int    pno, pcost;
    private String pname;

    void accept() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println( "Enter pno" );
        pno = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "Enter pname" );
        pname = sc.next();
        System.out.println( "Enter pcost" );
        pcost = sc.nextInt();
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println( pno + "\t" + pname + "\t" + pcost );
    }
}

class objarray {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int i;
        Prod[] p = new Prod[3];
        for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
            p[i].accept();
        for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
            p[i].print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Initialize array Elements(Objects) `p[i]=new Prod();`

Comment: well u need to create every time new object into the for loop. see.

Comment: +1 because u are at learning stage. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialize the elements of your array:

```
Prod[] p = new Prod[3];
for(i = 0;i<3;i++)
    p[i] = new Prod(); // added this line
    // rest of code
```

The statement `Prod[] p = new Prod[3];` just allocates *space* for the *references* to `Prod` objects - it doesn't create them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was of great help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Prod[] p = new Prod[3];
    for(i = 0;i<3;i++){
        p[i] = new Prod(); // this will assign in each
// rest your logic.

    }
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was of great help!

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the elements in the array to avoid null pointer exception to get a clear picture try eclipse debugger where you will know the place where there are null values and you can deal these issues in a easy manner